# how to search in sqlite if exist all letter of alphabet

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table of a database with the letters of the alphabet. 
I want to do a rawquery to know if some letter of the alphabet is absent in the table.

EXAMPLE:

TABLE

```
1-A
2-B
3-C
4-E
```

RESULT SEARCH = D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has no looping construct that could dynamically create values that do not actually exist in the database.
(Actually, [it has](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), but not in any version used in Android.)

So you have to create a (temporary) table with *all* letters, or use lots of constant SELECTs to construct a virtual table:

```
SELECT letter
FROM (SELECT 'A' AS letter
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'B'
      UNION ALL
      ...
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'Z')
WHERE letter NOT IN (SELECT letter
                     FROM MyTable)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. It is possible, to do the small query

Comment: Example query: SELECT letter FROM table WHERE letter NOT LIKE (all letter 'A-Z')

Comment: Read again the first sentence of the answer.

Comment: I have thought: 1.-it makes an array 'all'  (A-Z); 2.- to do a query to the table and that returns all the results. 3.-to spend the results to an array 'results'. 4.-to compare array 'all' and 'results'

Comment: That's the same what this SQL does.